# DNS stops working after few seconds

Tags: networking, dns

When I reboot my Ubuntu 14.04 server (with Zimbra mail system) DNS lookup works a few seconds and then it stops.

First I can ping my website but after a minute I cannot, see this:

```
hans@ubumail:~$ ping www.gso.nl
PING www.gso.nl (217.115.205.81) 56(84) bytes of data.<br>
64 bytes from 217.115.205.81: icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=3.35 ms
64 bytes from 217.115.205.81: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=3.19 ms
64 bytes from 217.115.205.81: icmp_seq=3 ttl=122 time=17.3 ms
--- www.gso.nl ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.193/7.961/17.342/6.634 ms

hans@ubumail:~$ ping www.gso.nl
PING www.gso.nl (217.115.205.81) 56(84) bytes of data
64 bytes from 217.115.205.81: icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=4.07 ms
64 bytes from 217.115.205.81: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=4.20 ms
64 bytes from 217.115.205.81: icmp_seq=3 ttl=122 time=2.91 ms
64 bytes from 217.115.205.81: icmp_seq=4 ttl=122 time=3.95 ms
64 bytes from 217.115.205.81: icmp_seq=5 ttl=122 time=3.24 ms
64 bytes from 217.115.205.81: icmp_seq=6 ttl=122 time=7.11 ms
--- www.gso.nl ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.912/4.249/7.110/1.362 ms

hans@ubumail:~$ ping www.nn.nl
ping: unknown host www.nn.nl

hans@ubumail:~$ ping www.gso.nl
ping: unknown host www.gso.nl

hans@ubumail:~$ ping www.gso.nl
ping: unknown host www.gso.nl
```

It looks something is overriding the name server settings after the reboot.

My network settings:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.168.20
     gateway 192.168.168.168
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     network 192.168.168.0
     broadcast 192.168.168.255
     dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

I tried different name servers, that does not help. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please add the entries of `/etc/resolv.conf`..Also when the DNS lookup is not working did you try to ping the ip directly i.e. `ping 217.115.205.81`?

Comment: I see there is something in resolf.conf that is comming from another service: <br># Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)<br>
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN<br>
nameserver 127.0.0.1<br><br>Where do I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill your name Server into /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
the content like this (samples):

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Then in shell command type : #>**sudo resolvconf -u** this is resolve my problem

Comment: If you are not sure about something please post it as a comment, not answer. OP might not be using `resolvconf` and `4.4.4.4` is not a valid nameserver.

Comment: I tried this. When I modify /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head insert the 8.8.8.8 nameserver and run sudo resolvconf -u then 2 name server entries are in /etc/resolv.conf the one I edited and this line "nameserver 127.0.0.1" WHere does the second one come from?

Answer (score 0):

The `nameserver 127.0.0.1` will reside in `/etc/resolv.conf` if you use `dnsmasq` based name resolution. To disable it run the following from terminal:

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/\(dns=dnsmasq\)/#\1/' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Make sure you don't have `network-manager` configured to manage your network, also remove any nameserver entry (if inserted any) from `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/{base,head,tail}`. Now doing the following should resolve the issue:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
```